# For-loop, return N times X in given range

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```js
const array = [];

const times = 3;
const count = 5;

for (let i = 0; i < times * count * 2; i++) {
  const a = i - (i % times);
  const b = a % count;
  array.push(b);
}

console.log(array);
// expected output [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0 ...]
```

Hello guys, how can I get the expected result? I need to, use **single loop, only math operators, find the value needs to be pushed with using only (i)ndex**. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Push N times(3) a value from 0 to given(5) in order.

Comment: A series of 3 from 0 to 5? So 0, 0, 0 to 4, 4, 4?  How many iterations I don't see a parameter that defines how many 0, 0, 0 to 4, 4, 4? Is it 15?

Comment: @zer00ne Yes, I've defined the iterations with (times * count * 2) in loop, but it can be tousands. Series and range also may vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is it, one loop, only math:

```js
const array = [];

const times = 3;
const count = 5;

for (let i = 0; i < times * count * 2; i++) {
  array.push(Math.abs(i % times - i) / times % count);
}

console.log(array);
// expected output [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0 ...]
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to do this with the main index without any other variable?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of ways to achieve the output you require. You could use two loops:

```js
let array = [];
const times = 3;
const count = 5;

for (let i = 0; i < times * count * 2; i++) {
  for (let n = 1; n <= times; n++) {
    array.push(i % count);
  }
}

console.log(array);
```

Or alternatively you can use a single loop and use `Array.fill()` to populate a child array which you flatten before concatenating:

```js
let array = [];
const times = 3;
const count = 5;

for (let i = 0; i < times * count * 2; i++) {
  array = array.concat((new Array(times)).fill(i % count).flat());
}

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the required value for each entry in the output using

```
Math.floor(i % (times*count) / times)
```

Here's a solution using a `for` loop and also a one-liner using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```js
const times = 3
const count = 5
const repeats = 2

function counter1(times, count, repeats) {
  const result = []
  for (i = 0; i < times * count * repeats; i++) {
    result.push(Math.floor(i % (times * count) / times))
  }
  return result
}

console.log(counter1(times, count, repeats))

const counter2 = (times, count, repeats) =>
  Array.from({ length: times * count * repeats },
    (_, i) => Math.floor(i % (times * count) / times))

console.log(counter2(times, count, repeats))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [];

const times = 3;
const count = 5;

// it repeats everything 3 times
for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    // count from 0 to 4 // do 5 times
    // it repeat loop while but with increased value every time
    // 0,0,0
    // 1,1,1
    // 2,2,2
    // 3,3,3
    // 4,4,4
    for (let i2 = 0; i2 < count; i2++) {
        // it push the same number while i3 is not equal to variable times
        // so 0 will be pushed 3 times 
        // 0,0,0
        let i3 = 0;
        while (i3 != times) {
            array.push(i2);
            i3++;
        }
    }
}

console.log(array);
// expected output [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0 ...]
```

Comment: Can you provide a short explanation of your code?

Comment: @MichaelM. start reading from the most nested loop

Comment: Can you update your answer to include that explanation? It will help others who are trying to understand your code.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this as destructuring the array .

```
let firstarray=[]
let array = [];

const times = 3;
const count = 5;

for (let i = 0; i < count ; i++) {
    for(let j=0;j<times;j++){
        firstarray.push(i)
    }
}
array=[...firstarray,...firstarray]
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This answer was started before last edit of question -- so no it's not a loop with a modulus `%`. It's a function that is Array-centric so with a slight modification can be used with other types as well.

I added an additional parameter: `iterations` which is the number of times the series of numbers should be repeated.

If @params were `times = 3`, `count = 5`, and `iterations = 15`

Working backwards since each set of arrays are blank:

```
[...Array(5)] // is ['','','','','']
.flatMap((_, i) => // will return the following for each ''...
Array(3).fill(i) // is [i, i, i]
```

result is `[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], ...]`
returned as `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,...]` since `.flatMap()` flattens one level of arrays.

```
[...Array(15)] // is ['','','','','', '','','','','', '','','','','']
.flatMap(_ => // will return the previous array of 15 numbers for each ''
```

Final return is 15 sub-arrays flattened to an array of 225 numbers in the desired pattern of:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,... 4, 4, 4, /* 15 times */]
```

```js
/**
 * Given a range 0 to a given number (count), repeat consecutively each number
 * within the range a given number of times (times). Repeat the process a given
 * number of times (iterations). 
 * @param {number} times - The number of repeats of each number ex. 0, 0, 0
 * @param {number} count - The total of numbers within a range starting from 0
 * @param {number} iterations - The total number of times the entire series
 * of numbers are repeated.
 * @return {array<number>} - An array of numbers in the following pattern
 * if times = 5, count = 5, and iterations = 15:
 *         [(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,... 4, 4, 4) repeated 15 times]
 */
function repeatRange(times, count, iterations) {
  return [...Array(iterations)].flatMap(_ => [...Array(count)].flatMap((_, i) =>
    Array(times).fill(i)));
}

const t = 3;
const c = 5;
const i = 15;
console.log(JSON.stringify(repeatRange(t, c, i)));
```

```css
.as-console-row::after { width: 0; font-size: 0; }
.as-console-row-code { width: 100%; word-break: break-word; }
```